# this.setState is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React 16 with Redux and i am using this.setState func onClick. But it is not working correctly. I tried to debug for hours and could not find any solution. Here is my code;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SSelect extends Component {
    state = {
        selectedName: '',
    }

    handleSelect = (id, name) => {
        this.setState({ selectedName: name });
        this.props.handleSelect(id); // this is redux action
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.selectedName);
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.props.options.map(option => (
                        <div
                            key={option.id}
                            role="button"
                            onKeyPress={() => this.handleSelect(option.id, option.name)}
                            onClick={() => this.handleSelect(option.id, option.name)}
                            tabIndex="0"
                        >
                            {option.name}
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SSelect.propTypes = {
    handleSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    segmentIndex: PropTypes.number,
};

SSelect.defaultProps = {
    segmentIndex: 0,
};

export default onClickOutside(SSelect);
```

`console.log(this.state.selectedName);` prints nothing, if i select same option on list, it prints true result. After select a new option, it prints empty again.

when i track my redux processes, i saw that it is working and sets new value to store correctly. when i remove my redux action, `console.log(this.state.selectedName);` printing true value.

here is my react and redux versions;

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try calling `onClick={() => this.handleSelect(option.id, 'test')}` then `console.log(this.state.selectedName)`.  If 'test' shows, that means that your option.name value is the issue and not your function.

Comment: `option.name` is not empty, i m sure because i am using it in div tag as text.

Comment: when i write 'test' it is working like i tell, i mean, it is working on second click. Maybe i should change my div tag to button or etc.

Comment: it did not work with button too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange but i solved the problem.

On my reducer, my key's name was `segment`. I converted the name to `selectedSegment` and problem solved. I think `segment` word is reserved but i could not find any doc about reserved words.

I will open an issue to react-redux

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem a simple way, You can set the `selectedName` manually and then you can do force update.

`handleSelect(id, name) {`
    `this.state.selectedName=name;`
   `this.forceUpdate();`
    `this.props.handleSelect(id);`
`}`

To redux setState
`handleSelect(id,name){
  this.setState({ selectedName: name }) 
};`
`onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this,option.id, option.name)}`

Comment: using `this.forceUpdate` is not suggested, also you can't set state like that.

Comment: `this.state.selectedName=name;` is working wor me with react + alt. see my edit for redux

Answer (score 0):

Unless my eyes are deceiving me, you have defined `handleSelect` as a class method and not an instance method meaning the `this` inside of the `handleSelect` function you have defined does not refer to your component.

You should define it as:

```
handleSelect(id, name) {
    this.setState({ selectedName: name });
    this.props.handleSelect(id); // this is redux action
}
```

rather than:

```
handleSelect = (id, name) => {
    this.setState({ selectedName: name });
    this.props.handleSelect(id); // this is redux action
}
```

Comment: This is the experimental [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Babel will transpile this to a bound instance method.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and it gave me same result. i am using ES6 and i defined all my functions like this.

Comment: @trixn - thanks, I forgot about the `static` keyword.

Comment: btw, it's not static in this case

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wrap the component with `connect()`?

As far is I know `connect()` makes you component `pure` (in redux terminology - props only) by default. It can be overridden in the fourth `options` argument of `connect`.

However most likely the best solution would be to get rid of internal state, because that's what we use redux for

> [options] (Object) If specified, further customizes the behavior of
>   the connector. In addition to the options passable to
>   connectAdvanced() (see those below), connect() accepts these
>   additional options:
>
> [pure] (Boolean): If true, connect() will avoid re-renders and calls
>   to mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, and mergeProps if the relevant
>   state/props objects remain equal based on their respective equality
>   checks. Assumes that the wrapped component is a “pure” component and
>   does not rely on any input or state other than its props and the
>   selected Redux store’s state. Default value: true

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: this is not container, this is a component which is in a container. i used `connect` on my container and pass actions to components. this is best practice of redux. https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components
you are right about internal state but i need this because it is a component which i am using many part of project.

Comment: it's just you are saying in your post `this.props.handleSelect(id); // this is redux action`, which implies that this is a container

Comment: In that case I would check the transpiled code, I suspect the constructor of the component can be not what everyone expects to be

Comment: yes, i said, but pass as props to component. i mean the root container is connected to redux and this is not a container, just a component. when i need to fire an action, i pass action as prop from container to component/

Comment: another options is to add shouldComponentUpdate , and set a breakpoint inside the method and see what's happening. you can make always `return true` to see will the component rerender properly in this case or not